# how to assign getElementbyId variable to html code

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I have an image of a person wearing a hat. 
I have «master.png» image of the hat (by itself) over this image which will change to a different image (same hat/different color) everytime the user clicks a different color swatch below.

The javascript function works but I haven't been able to assign the color variable values to my swatches. So only the last js src image listed appears regardless of which swatch you click.
I'm also not sure if my javascript variable code is correct.

I haven't been able to find anything on the web about how to do this.
Please help!

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hat(color)
{
var color = ['redhat', 'bluehat', 'blackhat'];
document.getElementById("master").src="images/redhat.png"; 
document.getElementById("master").src="images/bluehat.png"; 
document.getElementById("master").src="images/blackhat.png"; 
}
</script>



<img id="hat" src="images/manwearinghat.png" width="100%" class="center">


<img id="master" src="images/masterhat.png" width="100%" alt=" " name="master">




<img src="images/swatchs/redswatch.png" width="69" height="69" onclick="hat('redhat');" value="redhat" style="z-index:3">


<img src="images/swatchs/blueswatch.png" width="69" height="69" onclick="hat('bluehat');" value="bluehat" style="z-index:3">


<img src="images/swatchs/blackhat.png" width="69" height="69
" onclick="hat('blackhat');" style="z-index:3">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something as simple as this:

```
function hat(color) {
    document.getElementById("master").src = "images/" + color + ".png"; 
}
```

Comment: it is but it no longer recognizes them.

Comment: my previous code was longer but worked. the problem (i think) is linking each color swatch to its color image in the function. I have a feeling i'm missing some code in my html img section. Or my variable code is totally off.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already passing name of the color all you need to do is

```
  function hat(color) {
    document.getElementById("master").src = "images/" +color+".png";
}
```

to change the image.

Comment: Check the src text that is being generated before it gets set on the image. You can use firebug or similar tool for this. It should be "images/redhat.png" and not "images/'redhat'.png" if you pass redhat as color to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't very compact, but it will work.
HTML:

```
    <img id="hat" src="images/manwearinghat.png" width="100%" class="center">
    <div id="master"></div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/swatchs/redswatch.png" width="69" height="69" onclick="hat('redhat');"    
     value="redhat" style="z-index:3">


    <img src="images/swatchs/blueswatch.png" width="69" height="69" onclick="hat('bluehat');"
    value="bluehat" style="z-index:3">


    <img src="images/swatchs/blackhat.png" width="69" height="69
    " onclick="hat('blackhat');" style="z-index:3">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function hat(color){
        if (color == 'bluehat'){
            document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML=<img id="master" 
    src="images/bluehat.png" width="100%" alt=" " name="master">
        if (color == 'blackhat'){
            document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML=<img id="master"
    src="images/blackhat.png" width="100%" alt=" " name="master">

        if (color == 'redhat'){
            document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML=<img id="master" src="images/redhat.png"
    width="100%" alt=" " name="master">
    };
```